# Two JS functions for initComplete option in Datatable in Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables, dt

I try to combine two javascript functions into one variable so that I can call both in the `DT::datatable` initComplete option. The functions are working independently of each other, but when I combine them the table is not rendered.

JS function 1:

```
rownumber <- 8

jsc <- paste0("function() {
                           $(this.api().table().row(", rownumber, ").node()).addClass('selected');
                           this.api().table().row(", rownumber, ").node().scrollIntoView();
                          }")
```

JS function #2:

```
jsc2 <- "function(settings, json) {$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#2c3e50', 'color': '#fff'});}"
```

JS function #3 (the combined one):

```
jsc3 <- paste0("function() {
                           $(this.api().table().row(", rownumber, ").node()).addClass('selected');
                           this.api().table().row(", rownumber, ").node().scrollIntoView();
                          }
               function(settings, json) {$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#2c3e50', 'color': '#fff'});}")
```

When I run the last one with the code below, I do not get the desired result of a colored header row and that the focused is scrolled to the 8th row.

```
mtcars %>% datatable(
  options = list(
    dom = 't',
    paging = FALSE,
    scrollX = TRUE,
    scroller = TRUE, 
    paging = TRUE,
    initComplete = JS(jsc3)
)
)
```

I appreciate if somebody can assist on how to combine those two functions into a line of code that will render properly in the DT::datatable.

Answer (score 1):

`initComplete` needs one and only **one** JS callback. In your `jsc3`, you defined two functions. This cannot be accepted. You need to merge two functions to one, like below:

```r
library(DT)

rownumber <- 8

jsc3 <- paste0("function() {
                           $(this.api().table().row(", rownumber, ").node()).addClass('selected');
                           this.api().table().row(", rownumber, ").node().scrollIntoView();
                           $(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#2c3e50', 'color': '#fff'});
                          }
               ")

mtcars %>% datatable(
    options = list(
        dom = 't',
        paging = FALSE,
        scrollX = TRUE,
        scroller = TRUE, 
        paging = TRUE,
        initComplete = JS(jsc3)
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works. However when I use it in a Shiny app and the table is reloaded as a consequence of a reactive trigger, the scrolling works but the header color is no longer applied. Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Your question code didn't contain any shiny part. I can't tell what's wrong with your shiny code. Post your shiny code in another post and ask people to debug that may be a better option.